# Define Java POJO so Gson does not write value double quoted

Tags: javascript, java, gson

Note is this example javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        title: {
            text: "Using labelFormatter function of axisY"
        },
        axisY:{
            labelFormatter: function(e){
                return  "Y: " + e.value;
            }
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "spline",          
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 5  }, 
                { y: 9  }, 
                { y: 17 }, 
                { y: 32 }, 
                { y: 22 }, 
                { y: 14 }, 
                { y: 25 }, 
                { y: 18 }, 
                { y: 20 }
            ]
        }
        ]          
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

from http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/label-formatter/ that the value of labelFormatter field is not double quoted, and if I modify it to be double quoted then the code does not work.

I dont understand the Javascript rules for when it shoud/not be double quoted but it seems functions must not be.

I am trying to generate such code from Java using Gson, how do I create my POJO so that its value is not double quoted when output to json. Currently it is just defined as type String and therefore gets double quoted.

e.g

```
public class AxisY
{
    private boolean reversed;
    private int     labelMaxWidth;
    private boolean labelWrap;
    private String  title;
    private int     viewportMinimum = 0;
    private int     viewportMaximum;
    private int     interval;
    private String  labelFormatter;


    public boolean isReversed()
    {
        return reversed;
    }

    public void setReversed(boolean reversed)
    {
        this.reversed = reversed;
    }

    public int getLabelMaxWidth()
    {
        return labelMaxWidth;
    }

    public void setLabelMaxWidth(int labelMaxWidth)
    {
        this.labelMaxWidth = labelMaxWidth;
    }

    public boolean isLabelWrap()
    {
        return labelWrap;
    }

    public void setLabelWrap(boolean labelWrap)
    {
        this.labelWrap = labelWrap;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getViewportMinimum()
    {
        return viewportMinimum;
    }

    public void setViewportMinimum(int viewportMinimum)
    {
        this.viewportMinimum = viewportMinimum;
    }

    public int getViewportMaximum()
    {
        return viewportMaximum;
    }

    public void setViewportMaximum(int viewportMaximum)
    {
        this.viewportMaximum = viewportMaximum;
    }

    public int getInterval()
    {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval)
    {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public String getLabelFormatter()
    {
        return labelFormatter;
    }

    public void setLabelFormatter(String labelFormatter)
    {
        this.labelFormatter = labelFormatter;
    }
}




  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
        {
            title: {
                text: "Using labelFormatter function of axisY"
            },
            axisY:{
                labelFormatter: function(e){
                    return  "Y: " + e.value;
                }
            },
            data: [
            {
                type: "spline",          
                dataPoints: [
                    { y: 5  }, 
                    { y: 9  }, 
                    { y: 17 }, 
                    { y: 32 }, 
                    { y: 22 }, 
                    { y: 14 }, 
                    { y: 25 }, 
                    { y: 18 }, 
                    { y: 20 }
                ]
            }
            ]          
        });
        chart.render();
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont understand the Javascript rules for when it shoud/not be double quoted but it seems functions must not be.

You're mixing JavaScript code and JavaScript Object Notation (JSON). Functions do not exist in JSON (see its [grammar](http://www.json.org/)), the latter just serves data persistence/transfer responsibilities (exactly what [jjones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872038/jjones) suggests as well). Therefore Gson treats all strings as string literals -- and that's why you're getting your `function`-containing string to be escaped. This is the way it's supposed to work.

#### Security concerns

Another thing I would not recommend is transferring JavaScript code directly  in JSON. This is a clear security concern. I would better pass `labelFormatter` value as a simple name to let the front-end code pick up a proper function by name (what if someone sends `labelFormatter` as `function(){stealSessionCookies();}`?). Say,

(from the server)

```
{
    "axisY": {
        "labelFormatterStyleName": "y-by-name"
    }
}
```

(something like that at the client)

```
var labelFormatterStyles = {
    "y-by-name": function(e) {
        return "Y: " + e.value;
    }
}

var chartConfiguration = { // or something more JS-idiomatic to avoid field-by-field assignments
                           // I didn't write in JS for long time
    axisY: {
        labelFormatter: labelFormatterStyles[serverResponse.labelFormatterStyleName]
    }
};
new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", chartConfiguration);
```

#### If you're still convinced to do this with Gson

If for whatever solid reason you still need to generate such stuff at your server side, you can adapt your Gson to emit "more JavaScript-like" code.

```java
final class ChartData {

    final Title title;
    final Axis axisY;
    final List<Datum> data;

    ChartData(final Title title, final Axis axisY, final List<Datum> data) {
        this.title = title;
        this.axisY = axisY;
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

```java
final class Title {

    final String text;

    Title(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

```java
final class Axis {

    @JsonAdapter(RawStringTypeAdapter.class)
    final String labelFormatter;

    Axis(final String labelFormatter) {
        this.labelFormatter = labelFormatter;
    }

}
```

```java
final class Datum {

    final String type;
    final List<DataPoint> dataPoints;

    Datum(final String type, final List<DataPoint> dataPoints) {
        this.type = type;
        this.dataPoints = dataPoints;
    }

}
```

```java
final class DataPoint {

    final double y;

    DataPoint(final double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

Note that the `Axis` class has a field annotated with `@JsonAdapter(RawStringTypeAdapter.class)`. This is a special directive to tell Gson apply a special (de)serialization strategy. We can bind one to emit a raw string value. For example:

```java
final class RawStringTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<String> {

    // Gson can do it itself    
    private RawStringTypeAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final String value)
            throws IOException {
        // not out.value(value)!
        out.jsonValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        return in.nextString();
    }

}
```

Test:

```java
final ChartData chartData = new ChartData(
        new Title("Using labelFormatter function of axisY"),
        new Axis(
                "function(e) { return \"Y: \" + e.value; }"
        ),
        ImmutableList.of(
                new Datum(
                        "spline",
                        ImmutableList.of(
                                new DataPoint(5),
                                new DataPoint(9),
                                new DataPoint(17),
                                new DataPoint(32),
                                new DataPoint(22),
                                new DataPoint(14),
                                new DataPoint(25),
                                new DataPoint(18),
                                new DataPoint(20)
                        )
                )
        )
);
gson.toJson(chartData, System.out);
```

Output (partial minification mine):

```
{
  "title": {
    "text": "Using labelFormatter function of axisY"
  },
  "axisY": {
    "labelFormatter": function(e) { return "Y: " + e.value; }
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "spline",
      "dataPoints": [
        {"y": 5.0},
        {"y": 9.0},
        {"y": 17.0},
        {"y": 32.0},
        {"y": 22.0},
        {"y": 14.0},
        {"y": 25.0},
        {"y": 18.0},
        {"y": 20.0}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend you to generate JavaScript code at the back end: except of the security concerns, it's easier to change and redeploy JavaScript code.

Comment: HI, thankyou for this detailed explaination. A couple of things the code is generated in java but as a one off, i.e it creates a series of client html pages that are displayed there is not actually any server side scripting or server client html communication, so there is no real security concerns. But I think I have got confused, the original example http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/0r08tdka/ does pretty much what you recommend but I thought the chart.options part was more json, and so it made sense to me to move it to one place but I think you are saying this isnt actual json but javascript ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor Yes, that example at JSFiddle uses JavaScript to bind a formatting function. That latter is not possible in JSON, so that's why I was suggesting to return just a formatting style name and resolve an appropriate formatting function at the client side. Both JavaScript and JSON may look pretty similar (especially, the latter is a subset of the former), but some things cannot work in JSON by its design.

Comment: So actually I don't think they are using JSON at all, its all Javascript. Therefore the obvious question is there not a nice way to write Javascript data (rather than JSON data) from Java ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor In principle, you _can_ generate JavaScript on fly in Java using specialized libraries (if they exist, though, I'm not a specialist here), but this is complicated, error-prone to me and probably a wrong tool. You can use Gson, but this is a wrong tool here too -- my solution works just because Gson allows to write raw literals.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I would recommend you either generate JSON (with predefined style names) and write the JSON to your charts configuration mapper (that would recognize the style names and lookup for a proper on-client function). Or, if you're using a web server, just put a charts configuration-in-JavaScript skeleton into a template file and process it using a template engine (FreeMarker, Velocity, etc, or even JSP).

Comment: I only mean generate javascript data, i.e same as json data but without the restrictions. I'm suprised there is no Java library designed to do this, or an easy option with Json. I'm not using a webserver and for various reasons templating mechansim wouold not suit me. Its not a serious problem for me I can work round it, but I do like to try and do things the right way and there doesnt to be a right way. Your solution is valid but more complex then needs (would like javascript to be as simple) to be simply because there is a not a javascript data (rather than json) lib available.

Comment: Okay Im using your adapter method to use Gson to generate javascript rather than json, this works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Gson is serializing your Java POJO to JSON. JSON does not support function values. Value types supported by JSON are object, array, string, boolean, and number.

Comment: jjones in that example it is ouputting json is it not ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor no, the Chart method's options parameter is a JavaScript object, not JSON. Your labelFormatter property value is a function, which is not part of the JSON specification. Were your labelFormatter property value a type supported by JSON, then you could possibly use Gson to serialize your Java POJO into a JSON string and concatenate it to a string of JavaScript code that you would be outputting to the browser. However, I would say that serializing your POJO to JSON is not the proper way to handle this.

Comment: thanks I get it now, just confusing that the json and javascript syntax is so similar

Comment: I can understand that. JSON was defined as a lightweight specification for defining data structures to be communicated between systems, much like the more verbose XML specification (which I suppose could be confused with HTML lol).

Answer (score 0):

You can send the JSON double quoted like it is supposed to be and there you use this lib https://github.com/jcoc611/cassandraMAP

```
cassandraMAP.stringify({"key": "value"}); // => "{'key':'value'}"
cassandraMAP.parse("{'key':'value'}"); // => {"key": "value"}
```

Comment: So this would run in the browser, I don't really want to add this complety to the browser, I don't really understand are canvasjs doing something wrong which is a bit suprising since their standard of documementation seems pretty high or is Gson lacking, why does the function not work if double quoted ?

Comment: I didn't really understand your problem, I just took the point of double quoted to single to try to help. For a full understanding I would need a better explanation, or code you are not showing. What's the interaction of that java code with that javascript code, I'm not seeing where you're connecting both

Comment: Hi all my code is written in Java,  the Java code is a representation of json which is then converted into json using Gson  and is part of a html page created by Java.

Comment: I'm really trying to understand your problem lol. Look at my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Pass the labelFormatter function as string, and in your js you will need to put an eval in the value like this:

```
labelFormatter: eval("("+ <yourFunctionAsString> +")");
```

Comment: Thanks doesnt really solve the issue since all that code is generated by Gson and Gson wouldnt allow eval without a a double quote firstt i.e "eval - I can hack this in my Java code but I dont understand why I should need to,

Comment: JSON doesn't accept functions, tha'ts why you can't pass it without quotes, and JAVA string is always double quotes, that's why you can't use single quote there...
My answer here is to use eval outside the json, inside it...

Comment: but the whole 'labelFormatter: eval("("+ <yourFunctionAsString> +")");'line is json. However I think you have explianed the problem json doesnt support functions but they are using it to pass functions so a hack is required.

Comment: yeah you got it